# Can I use Hangfire with an existing entity framework code first application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, localdb, hangfire

I need to make a method run every 30 seconds - I was simply going to make a single page that was IP restricted and call it via CURL on a scheduled task every 30 seconds.

I was reading an article and learnt about hangfire - it seems amazing!

So, I have an existing application that is built on Entity Framework Code First - I tried using the default hangfire settings with the standard database, however I keep getting "login failed for user" yellow screen.

So, I was wondering, is there a quick way to make this just work within the standard entity framework tables\single DbContext, or, am I better off just giving it it's own database and login?

To update as per comment:

I am using a brand new MVC app and simply installed hangfire. The connection string is:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-myproject-20150404061144;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and I added:

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("DefaultConnection");
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
```

However, when launching, I get:

[image]

When I delete those three lines from the startup class, the application runs like normal - so, I don't understand what hangfire is doing that can't connect when EF can.

Comment: How did you configure the connectionstring for Hangfire? I don't think (well, I'm quite sure....) your problem has anything to do with th EF

Comment: That was my main question - I targeted the default connection string that is being used with entity framework and I am getting an error connecting to the DB (which works fine with EF)... and even if I get that working, I am worried things like DB migration will mess it up.

Comment: I don't think you will have problems using the same connection string

Comment: ...@PaoloCosta Well, I am! Hence the question!

Comment: @Wil, please post your configuration methods and the exact message you get. You can use Hangfire with any ORM, it does not mess up with migrations and other things, it even uses different DB schema to separate Hangfire's tables from your app's tables.

Comment: I find it a little odd that your connection string is missing "AttachDBFilename". Have you tried adding it? For example: 

<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnet-myproject-20150404061144.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-myproject-20150404061144;Integrated Security=True; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 2):

It seems Hangfire needs the database to be already created. In my case, I just ensured that it's already initialized:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("EFConnectionStringName");
```

What this does is:

- Create the DB
- Run the designated initializer (if we only call `CreateIfNotExists` we won't have the proper result in the database)
- Configure Hangfire to use the newly created db (`MyContext` uses the same connection string name)

Answer (score -3):

This is probably due to you are using a localDB for your project. 
Obviously, If you need to create Jobs and Hangfire somehow resembles a Message Queu, needs a somehow fast storage solution. LocalDB is anything but fast and probably lacks of many features Hangfire relies upon.

Comment: Actually, the Hangfire documentation claims support for "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (any edition, including LocalDB) and later, Microsoft SQL Azure" (http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html)

Comment: Yeap, but it all depends what your LocalDB verison is. The question would be. Do you have SQL Server 2008R or greater installed in your computer. No the Management Studio which will work with the server installed. 
I was using Management Studio 2008R on a 2005 SQL Server and did not have datetime2.